# Prove that a family of functions is uniformly bounded

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification

I consider $f$ a continuous function on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $F$ a primitive of $f$. I define the sequence of functions

$$
u_n(x) = \frac{F(x+1/n) - F(x)}{1/n}\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]},\quad \forall n\geq 1
$$

I want to show that :

$$
\exists M>0, \forall n\geq 1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R} : \lvert u_n(x)\rvert\leq M\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}
$$

My attempt : since $F$ is a primitive of $f$, it is differentiable on [a,b]. It follows from the mean value theorem that I can find for all $n\geq 1$ an $a_n\in[x,x+1/n]$ such that

$$
u_n(x) = \frac{F(x+1/n) - F(x)}{1/n}\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]} = F'(a_n)\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]} = f(a_n)\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}
$$

And conclude by the fact that $f$ being continuous on a compact set, it is bounded.

**However** as you can see, there is a problem since for all $n\geq1$ we can find a $x\in[a,b]$ such that the segment $[x, x+1/n]$ does not belong in $[a,b]$ but the differentiability assumption holds only $[a,b]$. So I don't know if this proof can be improved or I need to use a totally different argument ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: $F$ is only defined on $[a,b]$ so how does your definition of $u_n$ make sense? What is $u_n(b-1/2n)$ for example?

Comment: @peek-a-boo This is the differentiability of $F$ which is only on $[a,b]$. For the point you chose, if $b-1/2n$ does not belong to $[a,b]$ it will be $0$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh sorry, you are right as a primitive, $F$ is only defined on $[a,b]$ yes. But as it is written on the post, there is an indicator function for the case where $x$ is not in $[a,b]$ so there is no problem !

Comment: No you still misunderstand. Take $x=b-1/2n$. This belongs to the interval $[a,b]$ (well this $x$ is strictly less than $b$ so as long as $n$ is large enough it will be strictly larger than $a$ and hence belong to the interval). So the indicator applied to $x$ gives $1$. However it makes no sense to evaluate $F$ at the point $x+1/n$, because it is outside the domain.

Comment: So now suppose you modify the definition of $u_n$ to say that it is equal to the difference quotient if everything makes sense and 0 otherwise. Then you won’t even run into the issue you raised. Or I guess you could continuously extend $f$ be setting it to be constant outside the closed interval then you don’t even run into domain issues. So it seems like you have nothing more than a definition issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend the function $f$ to $[a,b+1]$ by setting $f(x)=f(b)$ for $b<x\le b+1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc This is a good alternative, thank you.